# Is it correct to say that a Riemann integral converges?

Tags: integration, terminology

I got into an argument with a friend of mine. He argues that it's correct to say that a Riemann integral converges, like improper integrals, as the result is always a number.

I said that a Riemann integral represents a number, so it's not correct to say that it converges, since a number neither converges nor diverges.

What's the correct terminology here?

Comment: So, you ask it here so more people get into an argument? :-)

Comment: I think it's common to say that an improper integral diverges if it is infinite, so in principle it would make sense to use the opposite of "diverge". Come to think of it, I have not heard anyone use "converge" for integrals, but it seems acceptable to me.

Comment: @quid: Ahah, well I was hoping there is some kind of right terminology!

Comment: Have you tried just searching for "the integral converges" with quotes on Google?

Comment: @CarlMummert: Yes, only results about improper integrals show up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An improper integral is a limit, so it is appropriate to say it converges or does not.

Technically, a definite integral is a limit, too. But it seems non-idiomatic to say that it converges. More often it's said that the function is integrable.

Comment: That's what I said. If a function is Riemann integrable, that limit is always finite, so there is no point in saying the integral converges/diverges.

Comment: When we talk about $\lim_{x \to 0} \sin(x)/x$, we say "the limit converges", even though the limit is technically a number. Similarly, it is idiomatic to say that $\int_0^1 x\,dx$ converges, because an integral is also defined as a limiting process.

Comment: @CarlMummert I don't say "the limit converges". I either say "the function (or sequence) converges", or "the limit exists".

Comment: @Carl: I think *idiomatic* means "as people actually speak" rather than "correct and understandable."  http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Idiomatic

Comment: The derivative is a limit too. Does it "converge"?

Comment: Yes, that is certainly what it means. And, for me at least, it is how I speak. I/we can speak of a sequence, limit, net, or integral "converging" (actually, these are all expressible as convergence of an appropriate net). When a limit or integral converges, I/we also say that it exists.  I agree it would be less idiomatic to say that a derivative converges.

Comment: Then I guess we have different idioms, which is totally reasonable given the wideness of the mathematical community.